# @HtmlRaw One Word

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

im trying to use razor to generate a url like this

```
<img id="currentPic" src="/content/img/@Html.Raw(Model.user.defaultImage).png" />
```

but the .png bit is being added to the @htmlraw syntax and is not compiling. I know i need to tell the page that @htmlraw is over. I tried using ; which worked - but the ; was also displayed in the string when displayed.

How can i get it so it would display like this. When Model.user.defaultImage = random1

```
<img id="currentPic" src="/content/img/random1.png" />
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

try adding a new set of parenthesis

```
<img id="currentPic" src="/content/img/@(Html.Raw(Model.user.defaultImage)).png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `@{Html.Raw(Model.user.defaultImage)}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need `Html.Raw`, just use

```
<img id="currentPic" src="/content/img/@(Model.user.defaultImage).png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a hack, but works:

```
<img id="currentPic" src="/content/img/@Html.Raw(Model.user.defaultImage + ".png")" />
```